# Equivalent for async_work_group_copy in CUDA

Tags: cuda, opencl, gpu

Is there an equivalent for the family of OpenCL workgroup functions `async_work_group_copy()`, `async_work_group_strided_copy()` in CUDA?

CUDA seems to have a build-in `memcpy()`, but is is per-thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing equivalent or similar provided by CUDA as a built-in capability.